# Implement Linq search query for n number of keywords and AND / OR option

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a textbox that takes free text as input for a search and I have a `LINQ` query that I want to extend with this type of search.

The input could be something like `"big blue car"` and that should result in a query that searches for titles that contain all these words.

There is also an option to switch to **"any word"** instead of **"all words".**

What is the best/easiest way to add this to my `LINQ` query?

The query now looks like

```
from b in books
where b.InStore == true && b.Price > 10 && title.Contains()...at this point i want to add the text search. 
select b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly reccommend you to do it with two queries!

But take a look at this, isn't it cool?

```
var searchAll = true;
var words = List<string>{"big", "blue", "car"};

from b in books
where (...) (searchAll && words.All(x => title.contains(x))) ||
            (!searchAll && words.Any(x => title.Contains(x)))
select b
```

But you really should make it with two different queries.

Comment: Indeed, that looks good! What exactly is the reason that you'd prefer 2 queries over this one query?

Comment: @TysHTTP. Well... It a question of taste. I think it's more readable in two queries. You're the boss! anyway it's cool and answering your's question. **:)**

Comment: Yeah, i guess so. Well my query has many more criteria in it, so adding this bit doesn't make it much more unreadable :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would first split the query and the title into words, and then check for containment.  A rough cut is

```
string[] queryParts = query.Split(' ');

books.Where(b => b.InStore)
    .Where(b => b.Price > 10)
    .Where(b => queryParts.Any(part => b.Title.Split(' ').Contains(part)))
```

for the any query, and

```
string[] queryParts = query.Split(' ');

books.Where(b => b.InStore)
    .Where(b => b.Price > 10)
    .Where(b => queryParts.All(part => b.Title.Split(' ').Contains(part)))
```

for the all query.

We have to split the title into words because the default [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method looks for any substring match, which means that

```
"ABC DEF".Contains("A")
```

returns `true`, even though for this purpose we don't want it to.

Note that both these solutions assume that words are always delimited by spaces, which isn't true in general.  Your user could type tabs in between words, use quotes to delimit groups of words (e.g. "New York"), and so on.

Comment: He's asking for a **single query** with the **two options** Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10158503/601179)